# Bash Script - Add element to Json Array

Tags: arrays, json, bash, jq

I have a json file like this:

```
{
  "id": 123,
  "guid": "XXXX",
  "isEnabled": true,
  "createdBy": "Admin",
  "updatedBy": "XXXXX",
  "createTime": 987654321,
  "updateTime": 79456123,
  "version": 1,
  "service": "XXXXX",
  "name": "all - consumergroup",
  "policyType": 0,
  "policyPriority": 0,
  "description": "Policy for all - consumergroup",
  "resourceSignature": "XXXXXXXXXX",
  "isAuditEnabled": true,
  "resources": {
    "consumergroup": {
      "values": [
        "*"
      ],
      "isExcludes": false,
      "isRecursive": false
    }
  },
  "policyItems": [
    {
      "accesses": [
        {
          "type": "consume",
          "isAllowed": true
        },
        {
          "type": "describe",
          "isAllowed": true
        }
      ],
      "users": [
        "XXXX",
        "XXXXX",
        "XXXX",
        "XXXXXX",
        "XXXXX",
        "XXXXXX",
        "XXXXXX",
        "usrpfm"
      ],
      "groups": [
        ""
      ],
      "roles": [],
      "conditions": [],
      "delegateAdmin": false
    },
    {
      "accesses": [
        {
          "type": "consume",
          "isAllowed": true
        },
        {
          "type": "describe",
          "isAllowed": true
        },
        {
          "type": "delete",
          "isAllowed": true
        }
      ],
      "users": [
        "rangerlookup"
      ],
      "groups": [
        ""
      ],
      "roles": [],
      "conditions": [],
      "delegateAdmin": false
    }
  ],
  "denyPolicyItems": [],
  "allowExceptions": [],
  "denyExceptions": [],
  "dataMaskPolicyItems": [],
  "rowFilterPolicyItems": [],
  "serviceType": "kafka",
  "options": {},
  "validitySchedules": [],
  "policyLabels": [],
  "zoneName": "",
  "isDenyAllElse": false
}
```

How can I add user, on Bash (maybe with `jq` command), (for instance: BATU) and array users

```
"users":["XXXX","XXXXX",...,"XXXXXX","usrpfm"]
```

turn to

```
"users":["XXXX","XXXXX",...,"XXXXXX","usrpfm","BATU"]
```

in this JSON.

Comment: What did you search for, and what did you find? What did you try, and how did it fail?

Comment: There are multiple "users" arrays. Which one do you want to modify? Only the first one, all of them, an arbitrary one, a specific one fulfilling a certain condition, …?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
  jq  '.policyItems[0].users  |=  . + ["BATUU"]' file.json
```

Use "|= . +" to add an additional array index (BATUU) to policyItems[0].users

Comment: `|=  . +` is just simply `+=`

Comment: jq  '.policyItems[0].users  |=  . + ["BATUU"]' file.json  --> it works.